# How use Arrays.some inside Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, boolean, observable

I have service that calls to server and retrieve list of id`s. I want to use some method to find if current id of user is equal to one of those Ids.

I tried:

```
 private isCurrentUserExistsInUserIdsList(): boolean {
        return this.userService.findIds().pipe(
            map((userIds: number[]) => {
                userIds.some(id => {
                    return id == this.currentUserId;
                });
            })
        );
    }
```

I am stuck here, how can I get the result of some method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the value inside operator `map`:

```
private isCurrentUserExistsInUserIdsList(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.userService.findIds().pipe(
    map((userIds: number[]) => {
      return userIds.some(id => {
        return id === this.currentUserId;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

You should probably have the return type be `Observable<boolean>`. You could also consider `Array.prototype.find` as another option.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I like to has all the observables relationated in the same service. So, you can

```
//in your userService:
public isCurrentUserExistsInUserIdsList(currentId:number): Observable<boolean>
{
     return this.findIds().pipe(
       map((res:any[])=>res.some(x=>x==currentId)))
}

//or, if you use the in the "map" "{" "}" you need use return
public isCurrentUserExistsInUserIdsList(currentId:number): Observable<boolean>
{
     return this.findIds().pipe(
       map((res:any[])=>{
        return res.some(x=>x==currentId)
      }))
}
```

So, you can subscribe in your component

```
this.isCurrentExistInUserIdsList(this.currentUserId).subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res)
})
```